# ios 9 push notification not showing while app is open

Tags: ios, swift2

```
if (deviceToken == nil) {
            print("There is no deviceToken saved yet.")
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
```

This my code for permission.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: while app is in foreground notification works but while app is open is doesn't show notification.

Comment: don't check saved `deviceToken`, user can change settings instead check permissions

Comment: yes right how can i check permission ?

Comment: This is not an iOS9 trait, this is how the APNS works in general.

Answer (score 5):

```
Need to add the completionHandler part, otherwise push notification is received. but it will be not shown.

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
  completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This method will not show the notification even with completionHandler.

Comment: This worked for me. If I didn't implement it, alerts didn't show when the app was open. When I implemented it, alerts shows as normal when the app was open.

Answer (score 4):

If your app is already open, no notification is shown but the application is responsible for updating the user interface or downloading new content.

Implement `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`
 to handle the notification, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:). here, you could create an alert that shows a title and message similar to the banner you'll see when receiving a standard notification.

Answer (score 0):

For showing alert view while running application you have to use:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Notification payload is in the `userInfo` variable. You have to decide what to do with it, how to show it etc.

Docs say:

> When the operating system delivers a local notification or remote
>   notification and the target app **is not running** in the foreground, it
>   can present the notification to the user through an alert, icon badge
>   number, or sound. If there is a notification alert and the user taps
>   or clicks an action button (or moves the action slider), the app
>   launches and calls a method to pass in the local-notification object
>   or remote-notification payload. **If the app is running in the
>   foreground when the notification is delivered, the app delegate
>   receives a local or remote notification**.

This means, when the app is running and receives a notification, no system alert is shown.

Comment: does this will show notification on top of application with details ?

Comment: No, this only happens when the app is not running. When your app is running and notification comes, it's up to you how to show it. Therefore you will need to implement a view that shows its contents.

Comment: i want to show like in every other app we have no top of current view .

Comment: This system alerts only show up when notification comes and the app it is destined to is not in the foreground. If your app is running in the foreground and it gets a notification you have to decide what to do with it - animate some notification view, update some labels etc. There is no system built-in notification view that you could trigger in this case. You have to implement it.